# Появляющиеся поля ввода на jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, css

Здраствуйте.
Имеется кнопка такого вида:

```
<div class="log-in"><img src="{THEME}/images/log-in.png" alt="log-in" /><a      href="">Войти</a></div>
```

И панель которая при нажатий на кнопку должна выезжать:

```
<div class="panel">
<form method="post" action="">
<label for="login_name">{login-method}</label><input type="text" name="login_name" id="login_name" />
<label for="login_password">Пароль (<a href="{lostpassword-link}">Забыли?</a>):</label><input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" />
<button class="fbutton" onclick="submit();" type="submit" title="Войти"><span>Войти</span></button>
<input name="login" type="hidden" id="login" value="submit" />
<a href="{registration-link}">Регистрация</a>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel{width:200px; height:150px; background:#F00; display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".log-in").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
        })

});
</script>
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатий на кнопку панель открывается, но при нажатий на `input` поле внутри `.panel`, то оно опять скрывается.
Помогите пожалуйста, или напишите, как правильно составить скрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря не смог проверить - у меня ваш пример работает как вы и хотели см. http://jsfiddle.net/chernomyrdin/rtkVQ/. Скорее всего есть еще какие-то обработчики которые закрывают panel.
Из банальных рекомендаций я-бы посоветовал убрать `display:none;` из CSS-а и добавить его в `<div class="panel" style="display:none">`

Comment: +1, сори когда начал писать свой ответ Вашего еще не было.

Comment: Попробовал, не прокатило(

Comment: Такое чувство что что-то еще происходит, на странице есть еще какие-нибудь jquery/javascript код ? И в какой версии броузера тестируеще ?

Comment: Все, разобрался)
У меня, оказывается, тег `{login}` стоял в `div.log-in`, то есть при нажатий на этот `div` он скрывался.
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Что я и говорил, закрывающийся тег не там стоял.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, на первый взгляд вообще должно работать.
Но попробуй, например, вместо:

```
$(".log-in").click
```

использовать

```
$("#log-in").click
```

А вообще надо целиком код посмотреть. Может у тебя где-то закрывающегося тега не хватает.

Comment: Тут все правильно `$(".log-in").click` так как `<div class="log-in">` и id там нету

Comment: :) хорошая шутка. Ну понятно, что правильно, но кто даст гарантию, что этот же класс у него, например не висит на боди?  <body class="log-in">